# Why does ^z have two ASCII codes?

Tags: c++

When I put the control key <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> at the beginning of the string, its ASCII code is zero, but when I put it at the end of a string, it has an ASCII code of 26.

Ex:

`^zhi` -->  ASCII `^z=0`

But

`Hi^z` --> ASCII `^z=26`

Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl-Z is a "Substitute character":

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character.
>
> A substitute character (␚) is a control character that is used in the
> place of a character that is recognized to be invalid or erroneous, or
> that cannot be represented on a given device. It is also used as an
> escape sequence in some programming languages.

As such, it can translate to different outputs in different contexts.